# Passing RadioButton Value data to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, radio-button

I'm trying to pass RadioButton value data to another activity, but I think the code is wrong because the data can't be viewed in textview at another activity.

Here my code in first activity java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText age;
RadioGroup jk;
Button send;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        jk     = findViewById(R.id.rg);
        age    = findViewById(R.id.age);
        send   = findViewById(R.id.send);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Next.class);
                    final Bundle b = new Bundle();

                    b.putString("age",age.getText().toString());

                    jk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            if(checkedId == R.id.male){
                                String piljk = getResources().getString(R.string.male);
                                b.putString("gender", piljk);
                            } else {
                                String piljk = getResources().getString(R.string.female);
                                b.putString("gender", piljk);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
          }
     }
}
```

and in my next activity java file

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        age.setText(b.getCharSequence("age"));
        jk.setText(b.getCharSequence("gender"));

        if (jk.equals("male")){
            int theage = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
            int HRmax = 220 - theage;
            hrmax.setText(String.valueOf(HRmax));
        } else {
            int theage = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
            int HRmax = 226 - theage;
            hrmax.setText(String.valueOf(HRmax));
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to get the `position` of the `button` that was `checked`:

```
 send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Next.class);
                final Bundle b = new Bundle();

                b.putString("age",age.getText().toString());

                int checked = jk.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                b.putString("checked", checked);


                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
```

and in your next activity java file :

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        age.setText(b.getCharSequence("age"));
        int checked = b.getInt("checked");


         if (checked==1){ // male
                    jk.setText("male");
                    int theage = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
                    int HRmax = 220 - theage;
                    hrmax.setText(String.valueOf(HRmax));
                } else {// female
                    jk.setText("female");
                    int theage = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
                    int HRmax = 226 - theage;
                    hrmax.setText(String.valueOf(HRmax));
                }
```